# How can I load my Excel dataset into R

Tags: r

I am doing a project about wind turbines where I test whether it is possible to heat a house only with energi from the wind turbine. So I made this R code. The code can predict the inside temperature. I have dataset in Excel that contains the outside temperature and windspeed every hour in january 2009.

```
R <- 5 This is the isolation of the wall

C <- 4 This is heat capacity of the wall

Ta <- rep(3,24) constant outside temperature in 24 hour 

Ph <- rep(2,24) constant effect of the wind turbine in kW in 24 hour

Ti0 <- 20 This is the beginning temperature in the house 

a <- -1/(R*C)

for(k in 2:24) {
  Ti[k] <- Ta[k] + exp(a) * (Ti[k-1] - Ta[k]) + R * (1-exp(a)) * Ph[k]
}
```

My question is. How can I load my Excel dataset into R so R can predict the inside temperatur with changing temperature in 24 hour and changing effect in 24 hour, instead of holding these constant

Comment: Did you search google or SO for how to load an excel spreadsheet into R?

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, find `R Data Import/Export`  link

Comment: Try the [XLConnect package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Use this to load Excel data:

```
data = read.xls("excelfile.xls")
```

This will get the data from the first worksheet in your Excel file and save it in a dataset.
(Just make sure the file is in the working directory).

Just in case this doesn't work, try loading the `gdata` package before importing from the Excel file:

```
library(gdata)
```

Comment: In the console or in the editor

Comment: Should work either way. You could start by testing in the console. Just read in the file and print it to see what you got.

Comment: if you have `.*xlsx` files `library(openxlsx); read.xlsx("file.xlsx")` is another easy way. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/